# Is it possible to convert an ISO file into a DEB file?

Tags: linux, windows, partitioning, ubuntu-20.04, android-x86

I got curious about installing any version of Windows on my system which runs Ubuntu 20.04 (64bit).

It was relatively easier installing Android x86 but I hit a snag when I tried using the same installation method for Windows. I searched the net for possible outcomes and I only ran into a few dead sites that made empty promises.

So my question is:

Is it even possible to convert a Windows ISO image file into a `.deb` file for installation in Ubuntu? If it is how?

Comment: This is an X-Y problem stemming from a profound misunderstanding. You didn't "install Android x86 with a .deb" either. You either installed it directly in dual-boot or used a Virtual Machine running in the Ubuntu host. The same can be done with Windows as the answer already published alludes to. You should be able to use the Windows installation ISO in any hypervisor (virtualization software) to install a Windows VM. But you need to educate yourself about this technologies to wipe out the huge confusion this question reflects before proceeding.

Comment: What @ChanganAuto said is correct: A `.deb` file is simply a software installer. And software installers are compressed archives designed for installing software. An `.iso` is just a compressed storage archive that is based on a physical storage format; like a CD or DVD. An `.iso` doesn’t really install anything; it is just an archive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, that's not how operation systems work. OS runs on bare hardware (imagine buying a brand new PC without <s>any bloatware shit</s> anything pre-installed, that's just hardware) but `.deb` files are basically programs on Debian-based distros (think of `exe`'s in Windows).

You can't and you don't want to convert an iso into deb. What you want is a Virtual Machine. Think of it as tool to run a virtual pc inside your real OS. To create a VM you need virtualization software such as QEMU (free, foss) or Virtual Box (free, partially open source, made by Oracle).

If you just want to run windows software on linux, you can use `wine` with no need to install windows anywhere at all. But you are probably going to have a lot of troubles with games, that's linux lol. What games? All work, no games! XD

So if you wanna game, install Windows as a second OS.

Comment: You read my mind

Comment: @KevinTazManda Accept the answer if it is helpful please

Answer (score 1):

No.

Deb files are packages compiled to run on (variants of) Linux.   The key thing is they are made specifically to run on Linux.  Its worth noting that not even all deb packages will work with a version of Linux - For example - x86 deb packages with compiled code wont work on ARM - indeed its very common to have different debs for different architectures.

You cant directly run Windows on Linux - they are competing systems (ie OS's).  What you can do is run a virtualised computer - eg using Virtualbox.  You can - with varying amounts of success - use WINE - a program which trys to let you run Windows programs in Linux.

Answer (score -2):

I created a VM using Oracle's software fine but I didnt want to go with that route due to gaming specifications.

My goal was to sideload Windows into the Grub bootloader to allow me to select whether I want to run Ubuntu, Android, or Windows on system startup

side note: Android_X86 is very buggy by the way! I dont recommend

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: @KevinTazManda This should either be amended to your post or added as a comment.  Answers really only should answer the question!

Comment: This site is a question and answer site. This all reads like a comment that should be posted under your question. Posting this stuff as an answer will only result in downvotes.

Comment: Just testing responsiveness

Comment: Dual boot is your friend